# Which point limit the speed in the network

Tags: bridge-router

I don't know if this is the correct place to ask this, my apologies if it isnt.

This is my home situation, however I want to understand the problem instead of only fixing it.

I have internet via a coaxial cable from Ziggo.

This connects to a modem from them a Technicolor 7200.
I have put the Technicolor in bridge mode and connected it to a tp-link modem ( I tried a wdr-4300 and an archer c7 V2)

Now before I put the Technicolor in bridge mode I got the 200/20 (down/up) mb/s speed via  an utp cable like I should.

However the WiFi is the worst so I have to put it in bridge mode and connect a better router.

After putting it in bridge mode on both the tp link modems I only reach 60/20 mb/s speeds.

I tried it with the Technicolor wifi on and of and the DHCP enabled and disabled. ( With DHCP enabled it did have a lot of issues getting the tp link to work)

In which point in this setup could be the limitation in the download speed? Since the upload speed stays the same.

When using the exact same tp link routers on another network they just get the maximum internet speeds . (500 down for the archer 2 and 350 for the wdr4300)

EDIT:
This issue only occurred after a merge of UPC which I used to have my internet from and Ziggo. The hardware hasn't changed.

Comment: Then it's the Technicolor. Its throughput capability seems to be  limited at 60/20 in bridge mode for some reason (maybe a packet fragmentation issue or a poor firmware). I think you should contact your cable provider and get help from them.

Comment: I forgot to put in the question that before there was a merger from my old provider it all worked fine. However the only change for me was the logo on the invoice the hardware and everything is the same. So if it would be the packet fragmentation or firmware  like you suggested how could this be possible when all is the same?  Can there be differences in the incoming signal?  I really just want to understand how this works and not only fix the issue.

Comment: First you need to prove that you can get 200/20 from the Technicolor in bridge mode via wired gigabit Ethernet from a LAN port of the Technicolor directly to a PC or Mac. If that works, then put one of your TP-Link boxes in place and see of you get full 200/20 from a wired LAN port of the TP-Link box.

Comment: @Spiff I configured the tp-link as an access point now. https://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-417.html. As ap the speed is fine with 200/20. So somehow only in bridge mode the speed drops. But if I put the Technicolor in bridge mode and disconnect the tp-link and reboot the Technicolor with only my laptop connected through a cable I get an internet connection and also get 200/20. ( In bridge mode I can only connect  or my laptop or the tp-link to the Technicolor.  The second connection won't get an internet connection).